# Prophet fails to install in Python

Tags: python, conda, facebook-prophet

I've been trying to install prophet through

```
pip install pystan
pip install prophet
```

but I keep getting errors. Then, I tried using conda to install prophet using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge prophet
```

But I keep getting errors such as,

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - prophet

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You haven't provided the error messages. *I keep getting errors* doesn't tell us what went wrong, so we can't suggest how to fix it. So I have to guess. If you are trying to install `pystan` on a Windows machine, one of the error messages reports the problem as: *WARNING:pystan:MSVC compiler is not supported.* Which is confirmed by the `pystan` documentation, which says that it does not run on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The Conda installation should now be working. The `prophet` package now has [a feedstock on Conda Forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/prophet-feedstock).

---

The Prophet package was [in the midst of transitioning](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/commit/360d294dbce0bbc9f1e262b77488cdf52f3b8fd6) from going by the name `fbprophet` in Python to what OP reports in the documentation, simply `prophet`. While this had already been updated in the docs and a PyPI version had been pushed, there was a backlog of review requests on the `conda-forge/staged-recipes` repository, where [the `prophet` package was awaiting review](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/14408).

In the interim, one should have continued to use the instructions from [the previous documentation](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/tree/57230997baf04f44e6d1359e08ccbc84a01dda3d), namely

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

and referred to the module by the name `fbprophet`.

Comment: But that is not in the instructions here: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html It downloads, but my code still said no module found

Answer (score 0):

I tried install prophet using

```
python -m pip install prophet
```

It helped me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).